How to alter the bins for a time vs counts plot in a non-uniform way
I have a time vs counts stepped line plot in R that I need to alter the bins for. Specifically I need to aggregate where the counts change by less than 10, but leave the rest as they are.
For example:
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
time <- c(0,sort(sample.int(365,50)))
counts <- c(1000,sort(sample.int(1000,50), decreasing = TRUE))
plot(x = time, y = counts, type = "S")


There are several steps from one time to the next that have a change in counts of less than 10. I'm looking for a way to aggregate these so that all changes in counts are more than 10.
I've tried using DPLYR to calculate the difference between counts and aggregate on that basis, however I can't work out how to do this when the difference is less than 10 across multiple counts (e.g. counts = c(57,55,49)).
I also tried to find if it coul dbe done directly within ggplot2, but came up dry.
Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Not sure whether you have solved this question after such a long wait?
Simple solution is to calculate all step sizes and simply delete all those dataframe rows where step < 10. However, this is over-zealous since some successive steps of <10 each will sum to >= 10. Lagging the data multiple times allows you to find the smallest number of deletes to achieve your aim:
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
time <- c(0, sort(sample.int(365,50)))
counts <- c(1000, sort(sample.int(1000,50), decreasing = TRUE))
plot(x = time, y = counts, type = "S")



df <- data.frame(time, counts)

# Need the dplyr::lag() here not the stats::lag()
df$previous <- dplyr::lag(df$counts)
df$step <- df$previous - df$counts

df$needs_binning <- ifelse((is.na(df$step)) | (df$step >= 10), FALSE, TRUE)

# Calculate maximum run length of <10 steps that *might* need binning
max_run <- max(rle(df$needs_binning)[[1]]) # lengths part of list
max_run   # 3
#> [1] 3

# From dplyr::across() help examples -----
multilag <- function(x, lags = 1:max_run) {
  names(lags) <- as.character(lags)
  purrr::map_dfr(lags, lag, x = x)
}

#multilag(df$counts)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("counts"), multilag, .unpack=TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("counts_"),
         ~ ifelse(. - counts < 10, TRUE, FALSE),
         .names = "{.col}_bin")) %>%
  filter(!if_any(ends_with("_bin"))) -> df2

head(df2)
#>   time counts previous step needs_binning counts_1 counts_2 counts_3
#> 1   26    895      908   13         FALSE      908      910      928
#> 2   41    880      890   10         FALSE      890      895      908
#> 3   43    854      880   26         FALSE      880      890      895
#> 4   69    818      847   29         FALSE      847      854      880
#> 5   72    774      818   44         FALSE      818      847      854
#> 6   76    755      774   19         FALSE      774      818      847
#>   counts_1_bin counts_2_bin counts_3_bin
#> 1        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
#> 2        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
#> 3        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
#> 4        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
#> 5        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
#> 6        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
range(df2$step, na.rm=TRUE)
#> [1] 10 61

plot(x=df2$time, y=df2$counts, type = "S")


Created on 2024-05-20 with reprex v2.1.0
